# Read Etag value before sending response in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, response, etag

I am writing a restful api in nodejs using expressjs as a framework. I have the following code

```
.get(function(request,response)
{ 
     Production.find(function(err, prods) {

        if (err)
            response.send(400, {success:false, error: err}); 
        response.send(200, prods);

        console.log(response._headers);

    }); 
});
```

Now I want to read the headers of the response before actually sending the response. I want this so that I could read the ETag value and hence check whether I should send the data again or not.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look ta [etag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/etag) node module? There are many modules available in npm for etag.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

`req.stale` might be what you want to use. Here are the docs for [req.stale](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.stale) and [req.fresh](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.fresh).

Both methods return a Boolean `true` or `false` which you can use in your logic.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.stale) return res.sendStatus(304);

    res.render('your/template'); // or .send() or whatever sauce you choose
});
```

Comment: You want want to check for fresh instead of stale, according to the fresh package docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fresh). Fresh requests should get 304, stale get rendered.